# Python: for loop not recognizing argument

Tags: python

My for loop is not recognising my argument. Its meant to loop through this CSV and print out "thats great" once it's found it in the CSV. From this code:

```
import csv
import sys

with open('fake.csv') as csvfile:
    sched = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in sched:
        a = row[0]
        class_select = input("What is your fav class in your sched ")
        if a == class_select:
            print("thats great!")
            break
        else:
            print("invalid option")
            break
```

I only got the output "invalid option" even though I typed in correctly one of the subjects. I'm not sure if I've forgotten to put something in there or if this isn't suitable for my goal.

This is the CSV if it helps:

```
class, time, duration, building
math, 10:55, 2hr, B01
religion, 3:45, 2hr, B02
PDHPDE, 12:05, 2hr, B03
history, 1:00, 2hr, B04
history extension, 11:00, 2hr, B05
```

Comment: You surely do not want to ask that question once for each row!  That's what you're doing now.  You need to move the `input` line out of the loop.

Comment: `row` also contains the header fields, so after first prompt it is going to compare your input to "class" and then print invalid option and `break` from the loop.

Comment: The break is there to stop it from going through the whole list after its found the subject that matches. As in once it finds the one that matches the input then it'll print the row it's in and stop.